# copy multiple folders of similar names from google cloud to google colab

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-colaboratory

I have a google cloud bucket which has 7 subfolders named `subset0` to `subset7`. I want to copy all of them to google colab. Right now I am using code like

```
!gsutil -m cp -r gs://mybucket/datafolder/subset0 datafolder/
```

to copy each folder separately. I am not sure how I can write a for loop to copy all folders without repeating the same line 7 times. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: You can use `gsutil -m cp -r gs://mybucket/datafolder/subset* datafolder/` assuming there is no `subset8`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @FerreginaPelona mentioned in the comments, you can use `gsutil -m cp -r gs://mybucket/datafolder/subset* datafolder/` if your `gs://mybucket/datafolder/` only contains `subset0` to `subset7` and no other subfolders.

However, if your **source bucket path** has other subfolders and you only want to specify your needed **subfolders**, you may put your subfolders in a list and use a **for loop** as shown below.

```py
from google.colab import auth
auth.authenticate_user()

# Download the file from a given Google Cloud Storage bucket.
subfolder_list = ["subset0","subset1","subset2","subset3","subset4","subset5","subset6","subset7"]
for subfolder in subfolder_list:
  !gsutil -m cp -r gs://mybucket/datafolder/{subfolder} /datafolder
```